# How can I check if my div tags fields are null or not and if its null do something with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 `div` tags with the same class. Each `div` tag has a textbox and a dropdownlist with numbers.

How can I check if all these `div` tags' textboxes and dropdownlists are empty or not and if it is "do something".

`$step` is an array with all of my `div` tags.

```
var $step = $(".wizard-step2:visible");
```

My Textbox have a class `Comment` and my Dropdownlist have a class `Grade`.

I have coded this so far but its wrong, I dont want it to check on each `div` tag, I want it to check all of them.

This is the code that is wrong:

```
var Comment = $step.find(".Comment").val();
var Grade = $step.find(".Grade").val();

for (var i = 0; i < $step.length; i++) {
    if (Comment != null && Grade > 0) { {
        // do this
    }
    } else {
        alert("You must enter both fields");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I think that I did not explain my question well, my code works like all of the answers I got on this question. I dont want to make this if statement to check each div tag. I want to be able to check if all of the div tags have any empty fields  do something " else if all the div tags fields are filled do something.

Users are allowed to leave the fields empty, but if all of the div tags fields are filled do something.

I do not want to do a if statement for each div tag, I want to do a if statement if all the div tags have any empty fields or if all are field.

Lets say I have 5 div tags. I have filled 4 of them and when I filled the last one 5 div tags are filled. Here I want this " do something ", else nothing should happen. I dont want the if statements to be executed on div tag 1, 2, 3, 4 that are filled I want the if statement to happen when the 5th is filled beacuse then all the div tags are filled else nothing should happen

Comment: Can you please also post your HTML

Comment: I recommend using jsfiddle, it makes it easier for anyone to play around with your problem

Comment: Its hard do that beacuse this is just a part from a wall of jquery code that i have :/

Comment: so - 10 all filled - do something, 10 all empty, do something else - in between - do nothing?

Comment: exacly! Thats what I am trying to achieve! :) but not all empty if just one field is empty and 9 are filled it should do something else

Comment: ok, that's a start - your question was indeed poorly worded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the filled elements of each class, and use the length of the resulting selections to perform your tests:

```
var $step = $(".wizard-step2:visible");

// returns true if the element's value is not null
function filled() {
    return !!this.value;
}

// count the number of non-empty elements
var n_step     = $step.length; 
var n_comments = $step.find('.Comment').filter(filled).length;
var n_grades   = $step.find('.Grade'  ).filter(filled).length;

if (n_comments === n_step && n_grades === n_step) {
     // all filled
} else if (n_comments === 0 && n_grades === 0) {
     // all empty
} else {
     // mixed - do nothing
}
```

Comment: My code does what your does. Please read my EDIT on my question. I think I explained it bad. I hope you understand my question after reading it now. Thanks!

Comment: My code does what your does. Please read my EDIT on my question. I think I explained it bad. I hope you understand my question after reading it now. Thanks!

Comment: When I said 5 if it was just example the amount of div tags can be anywhere between 1-20 it all depends what the user choose.

Comment: @RammtinAvar amended to base the test on the (variable) number of divs

Comment: Is it possible to do this to both :hidden and :visible? Beacuse when div tag 1 is visible the rest is hidden and so on..

Comment: @RammtinAvar sure, just get rid of the `:visible` pseudo selector and it'll test all of the divs, whether visible or not.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$(".wizard-step2:visible").each(function(){
    var Comment = $(this).find(".Comment").val();
    var Grade = $(this).find(".Grade").val();

    if (Comment != '' && Grade > 0) {
    {
        // do this
    } else {
        alert("You must enter both fields");
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, in addition, to be on the safe side I would specify the element tags too just in case the classes are asigned to other controls within the div later which may or may not need to be included in the validation.  somethign like this: `$(this).find("input[type='text'] .Comment").val();` and `$(this).find("select .Grade").val();` (Not sure if I got the syntax right)

Comment: Yes unless you are certain about these things you should always play it safe and make your selectors as specific as possible

Comment: My code does what your does. Please read my EDIT on my question. I think I explained it bad. I hope you understand my question after reading it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to get your comment inside of each something like

```
    var bOK, Comment, Grade ;
        $step.each(function(){
        Comment = $(this).find(".Comment").val();
        Grade = $(this).find(".Grade").val();
if(put your condition here)
else {
bOK = false;
return false
}
        });
// Now test your condition with bOK
```

Comment: My code does what your does. Please read my EDIT on my question. I think I explained it bad. I hope you understand my question after reading it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a collection or array like this:

```
$(".wizard-step2:visible").each(function(count){
    var isCommentEmpty = $(this).find(".comment").val().length == 0;
    if(isCommentEmpty){
        alert('Comment on div ' + count + ' is empty!';
    }
});
```

Comment: My code does what your does. Please read my EDIT on my question. I think I explained it bad. I hope you understand my question after reading it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the jQuery `each()` method to iterate over your `$(".wizard-step2:visible")` array of divs.

Have a look at this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/95377/1/) i've created to show how you can achieve this

**EDIT :**

This is the jist of the jsFiddle code here: -

```
$('.wizard-step2:visible').each(function(){

    var txtBox = $(this).find('.comment');
    var Select = $(this).find('.Grade');
    var thisDiv = $(this).attr('id');

    if(txtBox.val().length > 0 && Select.val().length > 0)
    {
        alert("values for " +thisDiv+ " are fine");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("please fill in both values for " + thisDiv);
    } 
});
```

Comment: The relevant JavaScript implementation should probably also be included in the answer just in case the link is dead at some stage in the future.

Comment: My code does what your does. Please read my EDIT on my question. I think I explained it bad. I hope you understand my question after reading it now. Thanks!